# Bind different DataTemplate's to interface implementations

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

This question is related to the accepted answer in my question: [Dynamic content in DataGrid or GridView CellTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65264951/dynamic-content-in-datagrid-or-gridview-celltemplate)

I have a collection of different datatypes to the ItemSource of the DataGrid, and depending on the datatype of the current index in the `DataSignalModel` collection, the corresponding DataType is to be used.

This the solution that helped me in the linked question:

> As you store a data type member instead of creating two distinct model types, you will have to create a custom DataTemplateSelector for selecting the data template depending on DataType.

```
public class DataSignalModelTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (!(item is SignalDisplayModel dataSignalModel) || !(container is FrameworkElement containerFrameworkElement))
            return null;

        switch (dataSignalModel.DataType)
        {
            case DataType.Bool:
                return FindDataTemplate(containerFrameworkElement, "DataSignalModelBoolTemplate");
            case DataType.Int:
            case DataType.Float:
                return FindDataTemplate(containerFrameworkElement, "DataSignalModelNumericTemplate");
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    private static DataTemplate FindDataTemplate(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, string key)
    {
        return (DataTemplate)frameworkElement.FindResource(key);
    }
}
```

And I want to follow the advice below.

> A note on data types: You keep a member DataType in your DataSignalModel to determine its type. Usually you would create specialized types for each data and not a one-for-all mode

So when I change my design to have an interface or base class and concrete implementation of the different types, how do I adapt my current solution to use the different DataTemplate's?

- Get rid of the custom DataTemplateSelector and somehow bind the different DataTemplates to the corresponding IDataSignalModel implementations?
- Adapt the custom DataTemplateSelector to return the DataTemplate on item type?
- Or maybe a different approach?

Comment: Not sure why you think you would even need a common interface or a DataTemplateSelector. You could put instances or arbitrary classes into an `ObservableCollection<object>` used as ItemsSource. Then have DataTemplates with appropriate DataTypes for all types you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind DataTemplate datatype to interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023441/how-to-bind-datatemplate-datatype-to-interface)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the previous answer, you would create distinct types for your data, e.g.:

```
public class BoolDataSignalModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // ...
}
```

```
public class IntDataSignalModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // ...
}
```

Just create as many models as you need. They do not necessarily have to share a common base type, it does not matter for data templating. I guess your data collection is still exposed like this:

```
public IList<DataSignalModel> DataSignalsList
{
   get { return _dataSignalsList; }
   set { _dataSignalsList = value; }
}
```

If you do not change your collection at runtime this is alright, otherwise use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0). Now, define a data template for each model in XAML with the `DataType` set to your model type, e.g.:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BoolDataSignalModel}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
      <Button Content="Click Me" FontSize="10" Height="18"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:IntDataSignalModel}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="0" Margin="10 5 10 5"/>
      <Slider Value="50" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" MinWidth="150"/>
      <TextBlock Text="100" Margin="10 5 10 5"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Please note, that you **do not** define an `x:Key`, otherwise it will not work. If you put these data templates in a resource dictionary in scope of the items control that you bound your collection to, it will automatically select the appropriate data template based on the item type. No need for a data template selector or a base class.

For more information, refer to [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `InheritanceDataTemplateSelector` which just works with interfaces:

```
namespace MyWpf;

using Sys = System;
using Wpf = System.Windows;
using WpfControls = System.Windows.Controls;

//PEARL: DataTemplate in WPF does not work with interfaces!
//       The declaration <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SomeInterface}"> silently fails.
//       We solve this problem by introducing a DataTemplateSelector 
//       that takes interfaces into consideration.
//Original inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/q/41714918/773113
public class InterfaceDataTemplateSelector : WpfControls.DataTemplateSelector
{
    delegate object? ResourceFinder( object key );

    public override Wpf.DataTemplate? SelectTemplate( object item, Wpf.DependencyObject container )
    {
        ResourceFinder resourceFinder = getResourceFinder( container );
        return tryGetDataTemplateRecursively( item.GetType(), resourceFinder );
    }

    static ResourceFinder getResourceFinder( Wpf.DependencyObject container ) //
        => (container is Wpf.FrameworkElement containerAsFrameworkElement) //
                ? containerAsFrameworkElement.TryFindResource //
                : Wpf.Application.Current.TryFindResource;

    static Wpf.DataTemplate? tryGetDataTemplateRecursively( Sys.Type type, ResourceFinder resourceFinder )
    {
        return tryGetDataTemplateFromType( type, resourceFinder ) //
                ?? tryGetDataTemplateFromInterfacesRecursively( type, resourceFinder ) //
                ?? tryGetDataTemplateFromSuperTypeRecursively( type, resourceFinder );
    }

    static Wpf.DataTemplate? tryGetDataTemplateFromType( Sys.Type type, ResourceFinder tryFindResource )
    {
        Wpf.DataTemplateKey resourceKey = new Wpf.DataTemplateKey( type );
        object? resource = tryFindResource( resourceKey );
        if( resource is Wpf.DataTemplate dataTemplate )
        {
            if( !dataTemplate.IsSealed )
                dataTemplate.DataType = type;
            return dataTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }

    static Wpf.DataTemplate? tryGetDataTemplateFromInterfacesRecursively( Sys.Type type, ResourceFinder resourceFinder )
    {
        foreach( var interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces() )
        {
            Wpf.DataTemplate? dataTemplate = tryGetDataTemplateRecursively( interfaceType, resourceFinder );
            if( dataTemplate != null )
                return dataTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }

    static Wpf.DataTemplate? tryGetDataTemplateFromSuperTypeRecursively( Sys.Type type, ResourceFinder resourceFinder )
    {
        return type.BaseType == null ? null : tryGetDataTemplateRecursively( type.BaseType, resourceFinder );
    }
}
```

How to use:

In your `Resources` section, define each `DataTemplate` as usual, where now each `DataType` is an interface instead of a concrete type:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MyViewModelInterface}">
    <local:MyView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then, add one more resource for the `InheritanceDataTemplateSelector`:

```
<myWpf:InterfaceDataTemplateSelector x:Key="InterfaceDataTemplateSelector" />
```

Then, at the right place which needs to make use of a `DataTemplate`, specify that this selector should be used. For example, in an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeViewModelCollection}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource InterfaceDataTemplateSelector}">
```

Note: the ViewModel interfaces ***do not have to*** extend `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The concrete implementation of the ViewModel ***may*** implement it, ***if needed.***